# I want to change the blank cells with space while reading database

Tags: r

Hi I am reading excel file and while reading i want to keep the blank cells as " " because after reading i am converting cells have text "no data" to NA.

do we have any solution for this , I mean I want to keep no data to NA and blank cells to " " space.

```
df <- read.xlsx("dir/db.xlsx")
df <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character),readr::parse_number,na='nodata'))
```

Comment: Check out `readxl::read_excel`. You could likely change the na argument to be something different (e.g. a generic string) and see if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Excel sheet has content similar to this example:

```
data.frame(
  col_1 = c(1, NA, 1), 
  col_2 = c("no data", 2, 2), 
  col_3 = c(NA, "no data", 3)) %>% 
  rio::export("db.xlsx") ## Exports the example.

db <- rio::import("db.xlsx") # Imports the example

db %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = ~replace_na(data = .x, replace = ""))) %>% 
  na_if("no data") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% # Optional
  mutate_all(as.numeric)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  col_1 col_2 col_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA
2    NA     2    NA
3     1     2     3
```

Comment: so in my actual data columns have only numeric values , and if i want to keep class as numeric for those column then ....???

Comment: I updated the answer according to your comment, str_rst.